# Class Group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Class Group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$

I used [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf) for my attempt. First the discriminant of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-15})$ is the discriminant of the monic minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+\sqrt{-15}}{2}$ (since $-15\equiv1\mod4)$, and obtained $disc(x^2-x+4)=-15$, so the Minkowski bound is $\frac{2!}{2^2}\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^1\sqrt{|-15|}\approx 2.47\dots$, and thus we only have to look at the prime $2$

[image]

since the factorization in the middle has different factors ($x(x+1)$), $\mathfrak p_2$ and $\mathfrak p_2'$ must be different and it remains to show that both are not principle, then the class group will be of order $2$, am I right ?

Is it enough if I show that $N\left(x+y(\frac{1+\sqrt{-15}}{2})\right)=x^2+xy+4y^2=2$ has no integer solutions ? If yes, can you explain it ? (I've already proved that $x^2+xy+4y^2=2$ is impossible, but why is that sufficient)

Comment: It is sufficient to show that one of the two is not principal, since their product is principal. In this case you have that the class group has only two elements.